# Does one need a type-theoretical axiom of choice for singletons?

Tags: axiom-of-choice

In Zermelo-Fraenkel axiomatics, one does not need to use the axiom of choice to resolve unique existential quantifiers, the axiom of replacement is enough for this.

But it seems that Type theory does not allow that: if you have a family of singletons, there is no way to get the family of its members.
If it is true, that can be proven by constructing a model of Type theory in which this does not hold.

I suspect that “homotopic” models can be useful there — there are families of contractible spaces which have no section, but I have no clue about how to do it for real.

Comment: If you have a family of *judgemental* singletons, then indeed, and the syntactic model is enough. But for instance using the existential in HoTT (which is also proof irrelevant, but propositionally so) unique choice is simply provable. The only problem here is that judgemental things are all dealt with by the machine, but "being a singleton" generally isn't decidable.

Comment: "If it is true, that can be proven by constructing a model of Type theory in which this does not hold." Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: AUC may not be the best way to accomplish what you want. You may be interested in a stronger [definite description](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.ClassicalDescription.html#iota) operator. But definite description is very confusing TBH.

Comment: @Couchy 
This sentence is related to my comment on Andrej Bauer's answer: if some axiomatic theory does not allow to prove a result, there exists (by completeness of first order logic, that should suffice) a model of that axiomatic theory (eg, of CIC) where this result is false.

Comment: That's probably true, but CIC is not a first order logic so you can't conclude that from completeness

Answer (score 8):

Let $\exists! z \in C . P(z)$ be shorthand for $\exists z \in C . (P(z) \land \forall w \in C . P(w) \to z = w)$.

Your question is related to the **axiom of unique choice (AUC)**: given a relation $R : A \to B \to \mathsf{Prop}$ satisfying
$$\forall x \in A . \exists! y \in B . R(x, y), \tag{1}$$
is there a map $f : A \to B$ such that $\forall x \in A . R(x, f x)$? Indeed, $R$ can be thought of as a *singleton in $B$* parameterized by $A$, and $f$ is the unique element of $B$ (still parameterized by $A$).

A relation satisfying (1) is called a *functional relation*.

Another way to state AUC is this: the *graph* of $f : A \to B$ is the relation $\Gamma_f : A \to B \to \mathsf{Prop}$ defined by
$$\Gamma_f \, a\, b \mathrel{{:}{=}} (f a = b).$$
Then AUC states that every functional relation is the graph of a function.

Whether AUC holds depends on how precisely we set up foundations.

In toposes AUC holds, so in particular it holds in ZFC and other set theories.

In Martin-Löf type theory AUC holds if we write (1) as
$$\textstyle
\prod_{x : A}
(\sum_{y : B}
R(x,y) \times \prod_{z : B} R(x,z) \to \mathsf{Id}(y,z))
$$
That's because we used $\Sigma$ in place of $\exists$, so we can extract the witness $y$. (Of course, for the same reason MLTT validates the full axiom of choice.)

In homotopy type theory AUC holds. Note that
$$
\textstyle
\exists z \in C . (P(z) \land \forall w \in C . P(w) \to z = w)
$$
is defined to be
$$
\textstyle
\|\sum_{z : C} (P(z) \times \prod_{w : C} P(w) \to z = w)
\|
$$
Because the type inside the truncation is a proposition, we may apply Lemma 3.9.1 of HoTT book to extract $z : C$.

In the Calculus of Inductive Constructions, i.e., the type theory of Coq, AUC does *not* hold when we use $\mathsf{Prop}$. This is so because we cannot eliminate from the proposition $\exists! y \in B . R(x, y)$ to $B$, unless $B$ itself is a proposition.

So the question really is: which formalism are you using?

Comment: Perfect answer in general, but I’d say it boils down to a slightly more specific question at the end: What definition/axiomatisation of $\exists$ are you using?

Comment: I believe equality also plays a role.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: Can you explain what you meant? Consider CIC and in IHOL: $\mathsf{Prop}$ and $\Omega$ are both complete lattices, and hence axiomatize $\exists$ the same way, but IHOL validates AUC and CIC doesn't. The difference between the two is in how $\mathsf{Prop}$ and $\Omega$ are situated within the rest of the foundation.

Comment: What I meant was that the specific formal systems you name differ in many ways, and many of those ways are irrelevant here.  The relevant differences are exactly the ones involved with the chosen treatment of $\exists$.  Regarding your specific example — I agree it comes from the difference between $\Omega$ and CIC’s $\textsf{Prop}$, but that’s exactly the difference between their two definitions of $\exists$: “reflection into $\Omega$/hProp”, vs “reflection into a primitive universe $\textsf{Prop}$”.  [cont’d]

Comment: And the choice of implementation of $\exists$ isn’t entirely tied to the choice of formalism. E.g. within CIC, all three are available: “existence as plain $\Sigma$”, “existence as –1-truncated $\Sigma$”, “existence as reflection of $\Sigma$ into a postulated $\textsf{Prop}$”.

Comment: Right, I think the present discussion just reinforces the last line of my answer.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. 
Are there references for what you say about CIC ?

Comment: @ACL: the discussion about AUC in [Yannick Forster](https://yforster.github.io)'s PhD thesis is pretty detailed and it explains the relationship between AUC and CIC.